# Port forwarding for MyCloud NAS Device

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nas, port

So I've got a MyCloud NAS device and I used to have port forwarding set up on an old router. I recently moved and have a new ISP so I'm unfamiliar with the jargon used by this one. I've got HTTP port 80 and HTTPS port 443 specified on the NAS software. On the router software, to set up port forwarding, it's asking me for optional LAN starting port, as well as WAN starting and ending ports. My question is, do I make 2 new rules where the WAN starting and ending ports are 80 and 443 for this device's IP?

Comment: can you post a screenshot?